# How to make three borders?

Tags: html, css

sorry if my question sounds *very* stupid, Im trying to learn asp.net .

Anyway, my question is, how to make three borders, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIE46.gif]

as you can see borders are at very left/right and logo(image) is at center
and rest of website have no border, not anything at all. just normal html.

I have managed to do some borders like picture I have given by looking at w3schools examples, but Im not sure if I did right, also when I made last border(the one at right) seems to come after logo instead of stickying to most right of web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Absolutely position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) the boxes on the left and right sides, then set left and right margins on the middle area that match the widths of the side boxes. For example:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">Pancakes</div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative; /* Needed for the position:absolute to work properly */
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.middle {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 50px;
}    
.right {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TNzn9/

Also, please stay away from w3schools, they [will lead you astray](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Okay, thank you. seems like what I want. about w3schools, I dont understand why I shoul stay away but since user with over 30k rep says that, I will. I guess I should figure out why soon

Comment: @4box: Don't trust authority too much. W3S provide a lot of incomplete and misleading information, they have nothing at all to do with the real W3, they're just trying to sell useless certifications by gaming Google's ranking system, etc. Read more at [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/). [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/), and [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) are better places to start looking for things. Then the real standards at [W3](http://w3.org/).

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div style="float:left;border:3px solid black;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"><h1>LOGO</h1></div>
    <div style="float:left;border:3px solid black;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"> 
The REST
</div>
```

Comment: move inline styling into css file

Comment: @Janez  - Sure, I am not going to program his job

Comment: sry for bad comment, I was saying that to 4box. my comment should be: "@fbox: ALSO move inline styling into css file":)